# Capturing body content of PUT method using JXBrowser?

Tags: jxbrowser

What is the best way to capture the body content of the PUT method using JXBrowser?

Using the BeforeURLRequestParams class users are able to call the "getPostData()" method. Is there a "getPutData()" method?

Answer (score 0):

JxBrowser 6.1 provides functionality that allows capturing POST/PUT upload data. The following sample demonstrates how to do it:

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.*;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.DefaultNetworkDelegate;

/**
 * This sample demonstrates how to read and modify POST data of
 * HTTP request using NetworkDelegate.
 */
public class POSTDataSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserContext browserContext = browser.getContext();
        NetworkService networkService = browserContext.getNetworkService();
        networkService.setNetworkDelegate(new DefaultNetworkDelegate() {
            @Override
            public void onBeforeURLRequest(BeforeURLRequestParams params) {
                if ("POST".equals(params.getMethod())) {
                    UploadData uploadData = params.getUploadData();
                    UploadDataType dataType = uploadData.getType();
                    if (dataType == UploadDataType.FORM_URL_ENCODED) {
                        FormData data = (FormData) uploadData;
                        data.setPair("key1", "value1", "value2");
                        data.setPair("key2", "value2");
                    } else if (dataType == UploadDataType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA) {
                        MultipartFormData data = (MultipartFormData) uploadData;
                        data.setPair("key1", "value1", "value2");
                        data.setPair("key2", "value2");
                        data.setFilePair("file3", "C:\\Test.zip");
                    } else if (dataType == UploadDataType.PLAIN_TEXT) {
                        TextData data = (TextData) uploadData;
                        data.setText("My data");
                    } else if (dataType == UploadDataType.BYTES) {
                        BytesData data = (BytesData) uploadData;
                        data.setData("My data".getBytes());
                    }
                    // Apply modified upload data that will be sent to a web server.
                    params.setUploadData(uploadData);
                }
            }
        });
        browser.loadURL(new LoadURLParams("http://localhost/", "key=value"));
    }
}
```